# How to plot multiple plots in unicodeplots.jl?

Tags: julia

I want to plot multiple lines(here simplified as two), but don't know how to draw in different colors on same plot.  Here is the separated figures version.

```
using UnicodePlots, DataFrames
function job()
    names, data = ["A", "B"], [
       DataFrame("x"=>[1, 2, 3], "y"=>[3, 5, 7]),
       DataFrame("x"=>[1, 2, 3], "y"=>[8, 2, 6]),
       ]
    y_min, y_max = typemax(Int64), typemin(Int64)
    y_min = min(minimum(data[1].y), minimum(data[2].y))
    y_max = max(maximum(data[1].y), maximum(data[2].y))
    ylim = (y_min, y_max)
    for i = 1:length(names)
        p = lineplot(data[i].x, data[i].y, name=names[i], ylim=ylim)
        show(p)
        println("")
        #if i == 1  
        #    p=lineplot(data[i].x, data[i].y, name=names[i], ylim=ylim)
        #else  # failed for p undefined when i == 2
        #    lineplot!(p, data[i].x, data[i].y, name=names[i], ylim=ylim)
        #end
    end
    #show(p)
    println("")
end
job()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was almost correct. Here is the fixed version:

```
using UnicodePlots, DataFrames
function job()
    names, data = ["A", "B"], [
       DataFrame("x"=>[1, 2, 3], "y"=>[3, 5, 7]),
       DataFrame("x"=>[1, 2, 3], "y"=>[8, 2, 6]),
       ]
    y_min, y_max = typemax(Int64), typemin(Int64)
    y_min = min(minimum(data[1].y), minimum(data[2].y))
    y_max = max(maximum(data[1].y), maximum(data[2].y))
    ylim = (y_min, y_max)
    local p
    for i = 1:length(names)
        if i == 1  
            p=lineplot(data[i].x, data[i].y; name=names[i], ylim=ylim)
        else
            lineplot!(p, data[i].x, data[i].y; name=names[i])
        end
    end
    show(p)
    println("")
end
job()
```

Issues were:

- When adding another line, cannot change axis.
- Variables inside loops need to be defined outside to extend their scope.

Think that's it.

Comment: @DanielYCLin You are right. It is just the y-axis which can't be changed (naturally).